# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\Faculties\show.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

this is my model Faculty

```
<?php


namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Faculty extends Model { protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'id', 'date_of_birth', 'age', 'qualification', 'religion', 'gender', 'phone_number', 'address', 'blood_group', 'email' ]; }
```

this is my FacultiesController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Faculty;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FacultiesController extends Controller
{
public function show(Faculty $faculty)
{
    $faculties = Faculty::where('id',$faculty->id)->first();

    return view('Faculties.show',['Faculty'=>$faculties]);
}
}
```

this is my route web.php

```
Route::resource('Faculties','FacultiesController');
```

this is my blade file show.blade.php

```
<ul>

    <li class="list-group-item">{{ $Faculty->name }}</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems here.

First, this is unnecessary:

```
public function show(Faculty $faculty)
{
    $faculties = Faculty::where('id',$faculty->id)->first();
```

The routing logic already passes the Faculty model to your function, so you're looking it up twice (and you can also simplify such logic by using `Faculty::find()` instead of `where()->first()`).

This should work fine:

```
public function show(Faculty $faculty)
{
    return view('Faculties.show',['Faculty'=>$faculty]);
}
```

If it doesn't, it may be that there's no Faculty model in your database matching that ID.

Comment: the faculty model is    `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Faculty extends Model
{
      protected $fillable = [
          'name',
          'id',
          'date_of_birth',
          'age',
          'qualification',
          'religion',
          'gender',
          'phone_number',
          'address',
          'blood_group',
          'email'
      ];
}
`

Comment: i already included the data in database also but it doesn't work

Comment: i appears as empty it didn't fetch the data from database @ceejayoz is there any correction in my blade.php file??